# Plotting pandas dataframes with PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm having problems plotting a `pandas` dataframe that has a `PeriodIndex`.

My data has gaps, and I want to achieve the following:

- Gaps should remain gaps, without interpolation;
- As each value is valid over the entire time period, the value should be shown as a horizontal line over the entire period.
- Nice-to-have: no vertical line at the period boundaries.

#Example

```
yearly = pd.DataFrame({'avSpeed': [50, 40, 20, 16]}, index=pd.PeriodIndex(['2014', '2015', '2018', '2019'], freq='A'))

      avSpeed
2014       50
2015       40
2018       20
2019       16
```

## My code so-far

- Make dataframe gapless by filling gaps with `NaN` (by resampling at unchanged frequency):

  ```
    yearly2 = yearly.resample('A').mean()

          avSpeed
    2014     50.0
    2015     40.0
    2016      NaN
    2017      NaN
    2018     20.0
    2019     16.0
  ```
- Plot this with `steps-post`:

  ```
    plt.figure()
    yearly2['avSpeed'].plot(color='red', drawstyle='steps-post')
  ```

  [image]

What's still missing:

- Main problem: the value for 2019 is only shown at the year's start.
- Also: vertical connecting lines are present (unwanted).

Comment: For the first question, add one more year (2020) with value of 2019?

Comment: @QuangHoang, thanks for your suggestion, but corrupting the data like is a guaranteed way to get extremely confused extremely fast :)

Comment: @ElRudi If the answers helped by solving your problem, I'd be grateful for an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hlines` with the `pandas.PeriodIndex` attributes `start_time` and `end_time`

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.hlines(yearly, yearly.index.start_time, yearly.index.end_time, 'r', label='avSpeed')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice solution. But it makes plotting with legends more complicated, since it will plot one entry per year. At least one more LOC is required to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks exactly how I want it, but as @Scotty1- mentions, messes up the legend. Also, I have many situations like this, so that will be many loops, though I suppose I can write a small function for that. Thanks!

Comment: I've found a better way, by passing the data as arrays: `ax.hlines(yearly.avSpeed,  yearly.index.start_time, (yearly.index+1).start_time, 'r')` does it in one go, and also creates only a single legend entry. I'll add it to my question so I can also show the image. Many thanks!

Comment: You taught me something too.  You are choosing to use `yearly.index` and `yearly.index + 1`.  As the index is of Period type those values are Periods.  You want to plot the datetime values.  Those are conveniently stored in the `start_time` and `end_time` attributes.  I suggest you use those values instead.

Comment: @ElRudi I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is only the last period you are having trouble with, simply appending a new period with an offset of 1 year filled with nan will solve your problem:

```
yearly2.loc[yearly2.index[-1] + pd.offsets.YearEnd(1), :] = np.nan
```

Specifying the `pd.offset` with `YearEnd` will retain your `PeriodIndex` frequency, which is `A-DEC` when resampling/creating the `PeriodIndex` with `freq='A'`. For other period frequencies, other offsets should of course be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I slightly modified it to `yearly2.loc[yearly.index[-1]+1,:] = np.nan` to work for other frequencies as well. Still, I'm not a fan, because it solves a problem with the graphing with changes to the data, which I'm reluctant to do.

Answer (score 0):

No need to upsample the data or even filling its gaps with `NaN`. You can plot the data as `hlines` like so:

```
ax=plt.subplot()
ax.hlines(yearly['avSpeed'],  yearly.index.start_time, (yearly.index+1).start_time, 'r') #or: yearly.index.end_time
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Many thanks [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905763/5446749) for pointing me in the right direction.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55904964/3) to the question [Plotting pandas dataframes with PeriodIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904964/plotting-pandas-dataframes-with-periodindex) by the OP [ElRudi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302262/elrudi) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>